# Android phone accessing database installed on other PC

Tags: php, android, android-emulator

I have installed XAMPP on my PC and I am writing android Java code to access the database in XAMPP as follows:

```
HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/mrs/authorization.php");
```

Here, 10.0.2.2 is only for android emulator (virtual device), it does not work for actual android device.

My question is: How can I make the actual android device able to connect the database server?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 10.0.2.2 you should use the local LAN ip address of your server pc. And your device should be in the same W(LAN).

No need for hotspots or other silly things.

Comment: The hotspot solution only requires that you have admin access to your pc,  there *may* be difficulties putting a device on the same WLAN, eg corporate policies, or home router firewalls which are not easily configurable.